# How to start a loop on a QThread

Tags: c++, loops, qt, qthread, qtimer

How can I start a loop on a different thread by pressing a `QPushButton`?

The main idea is, when `pushButtonStart` is clicked, start a **loop** on a `QThread`, and when `pushButtonStop` is clicked, stops the **loop** in the `QThread`.

The loop can be done by `QTimer`, `for` loop or `while` loop, but he needs a way to stop by pressing a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this code to create a new timer and set up a connection when it fires. This is in the Start code.

```
checkTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect( checkTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(checkTimerFired()) );
checkTimer->start(3000);
```

My "stop running" button sets programCreated to false, and checkTimerFired starts with this:

```
if (!programCreated) {
    checkTimer->stop();
    return;
}
```

That should be the Qt-specific things you need. The rest is simple C++.

Comment: That is the timer to run the function I think, probaly inside of SLOT() Is the name of the function?

Comment: I finally understand your code, but it took me a while because Im beginner on Qt and C++. I answered my own question with a best approach to beginner users!

Comment: @JoãoPedro You're jumping into the deep end trying to learn C++ and Qt at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To do the loop, I use `QTimer`, which run the slot `pressButton` multiple times until `stop();` function of `QTimer` is executed. Of course, to use this method I have to recode the program, to improve the algorithm.

`QTimer` loop:

```cpp
void MainPrograma::on_pushTurnOn_clicked()
{
    tierLoop = new QTimer(this);
    timerLoop->setInterval(5000);
    timerLoop->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(timerLoop, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(on_pushTurnOn_clicked()));
    
    QPushButton *ThirdButton = uimain->QPushButton_3;
    Nmb2 = 2
    Nmb4 = 4;

    if(Busy==1){
        ThirdButton->setEnabled(false);
    }
    if(Busy==0){

        timerLoop->start(); //start the loop

        StartFunction(Nmb2, Nmb4);
        if(X==1){
            ThirdButton->setEnabled(false);     
        }
        if(X==0){
            ThirdButton->setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}

void MainPrograma::on_pushTurnOff_clicked()
{
    timerLoop->stop(); //stop the loop
}
```

`QTimer` declaration on .h:

```cpp
private:
    QTimer *timerLoop;
```

I still do not understand how to use `QThread`... But the loop is already answered!